# Array explode with condition

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm facing a problem that I can't solve on my own, I can't find a way to do it.

I have those two strings:

```
'Germany, "Sightseeing, Travelling, Hotels"'
```

and

```
'Health, Medicin, Healthcare'
```

I need to `explode()` this strings on the `,` char, but only if the text, where this `,` lays in isn't surrounded by `"`.

So, as example this would be the desired results:

```
array(0 => 'Germany', 1 => '"Sightseeing, Travelling, Hotels"');
array(0 => 'Health', 1 => 'Medicin', 2 => 'Healthcare');
```

By now this is what I have:

```
explode(",", 'Germany, "Sightseeing, Travelling, Hotels"');
```

Which will give out

```
array(0 => 'Germany', 1 => '"Sightseeing', 2 => 'Travelling', 3 => 'Hotels"');
```

How can I get to this result?

Comment: Are you trying to *parse a CSV*?

Comment: @deceze I'm going through a CSV line by line, I need to generate categories based on those example string I provided. Now "Sightseeing, Travelling, Hotels" is a single category, not 3 seperated ones.

Comment: Show the code you have wriiten so far.

Comment: So, have you tried using a ***CSV parser***?

Comment: @deceze I didn't know that there are functions for that in PHP and my I couldn't find something in my research. But I never searched for CSV parsing, thanks for pointing it out to me, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Typing "CSV" into [PHP's manual's](http://php.net) search box should have come up with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-getcsv.php) how to parse csv (even if you are not reading a csv file, this is exactly what this string looks like):

```
<?php
print_r(str_getcsv('Germany, "Sightseeing, Travelling, Hotels"', ','));
print_r(str_getcsv('Health, Medicin, Healthcare'));
print_r(str_getcsv('D"uh!, \"Test\"', ','));
?>
```

results in:

```
Array ( [0] => Germany [1] => Sightseeing, Travelling, Hotels )
Array ( [0] => Health [1] => Medicin [2] => Healthcare )
Array ( [0] => D"uh! [1] => "Test" )
```

Remarks: This Function is available beginning with php version 5.3.0 and can also be configured as to what your input looks like. I added some special cases, this is a classic problem that looks far simpler than it is.

Comment: Great, this is excactly what I needed, didn't know there's an function for that in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php function [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

Here an example:

```
$string_1 = 'Germany, "Sightseeing, Travelling, Hotels"';
$string_2 = 'Health, Medicin, Healthcare';

$result_1 = str_getcsv($string_1,',','"');
$result_2 = str_getcsv($string_2,',','"');

print_R($result_1);
print_R($result_2);
```

that outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Germany
    [1] => Sightseeing, Travelling, Hotels
)
Array
(
    [0] => Health
    [1] =>  Medicin
    [2] =>  Healthcare
)
```

You can after map each element of the resultant array, and if there is a comma you can surround it with **"**

```
foreach($result_1 as $i => $item) {
    if(substr_count($item,',') > 0) {
        $result_1[$i] = '"'.$item.'"';
    }
}
```

Wich produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Germany
    [1] => "Sightseeing, Travelling, Hotels"
)
```